# Why can't the asset builder find

Tags: drupal-8

With Drupal 8 + CiviCRM 5.30.1

The asset builder is unable to find the crm-menubar.css file, i.e. this url:

https://example.org/civicrm/asset/builder?an=crm-menubar.css

gives me:

Unrecognized asset name: crm-menubar.css

[after updating /Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php to catch the error, previously it was generating error pages]

Any thoughts about how to debug this? I've checked and re-checked the urls/paths and everything else seems to be found properly. I see the crm-menubar.css file in the locations I would expect ...

The Drupal asset injector is installed - is it possible that might be interfering?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this on another site as well, both were upgraded from earlier, but not a lot earlier, versions, and both use the now-standard composer installation methods (drupal-recommended + the four civi requires, i.e. not the roundearth method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer to the Issue

The origin of the problem is when you ignore this: https://civicrm.org/blog/daved/action-required-drupal-8-installs-and-upgrades-composer-and-patches

To fix an existing installation which was upgraded or installed without the 'enable-patching' configuration, you can can do this:

```
composer config 'extra.enable-patching' true
composer update civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin civicrm/civicrm-core civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 civicrm/civicrm-packages  --with-dependencies
```

### Original Post

I figured out that if you run

```
composer config 'extra.enable-patching' true
```

straight after

```
composer create-project ...
```

installation is going to work.

Background:
We have a scripted install which worked fine with 5.28.4 so I thought
to upgrade to 5.30.1 but got the following message at

```
cv upgrade:db
```

```
vendor/bin/cv upgrade:db
Found CiviCRM database version 5.28.4.
Found CiviCRM code version 5.30.1.
Checking pre-upgrade messages...
_Pre-announcement for upcoming version 5.30_: If your composer
configuration or composer.json does not enable patching, you MUST do that
BEFORE running composer to update your files to version 5.30. Either by
using `composer config 'extra.enable-patching' true`, or updating the top
level composer.json's extra section with `"enable-patching": true`. See
Drupal 8 installation guide [1] for details.
The default copies of the message templates listed below will be updated to
handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation has customized
versions of these message templates, and you will need to apply the updates
manually after running this upgrade. Click here [2] for detailed
instructions. 

    * _Events - Registration Confirmation Invite_ - Support negative hours for
cancellation/transfer
    * _Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)_ - Support
negative hours for cancellation/transfer

The default copies of the message templates listed below will be updated to
handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation has customized
versions of these message templates, and you will need to apply the updates
manually after running this upgrade. Click here [2] for detailed
instructions. 

    * _Contributions - Invoice_ - Ensure that amount paid is shown even when
fully paid



Links:
------
[1] https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8
[2] https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates/#modifying-system-workflow-message-templates
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that seems useful. Any idea what gets patched? i.e. if I've upgraded without that already, what's the patch that would need to be applied?

Comment: If you upgraded to 5.30 without it, and you have "mysql:" in your DSN strings, you would notice right away since it wouldn't be able to connect to the database. See also https://civicrm.org/blog/daved/action-required-drupal-8-installs-and-upgrades-composer-and-patches. If you did upgrade and that happened, then enable patching and run `composer install` and hopefully should get back on track. But that seems different from the original asset issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the enable-patching note. I've confirmed that I can do the composer config after the fact and then run composer update on the four civicrm required packages with dependencies - that will re-install and patch approx. 10 packages. Logging in again and it's now working!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem - I think it came down to CiviCRM being installed incorrectly.

This is how the files sit in the now working copy:

```
user@server /var/www/html/site/drupal $ find -type d -name civicrm
./web/modules/contrib/civicrm
./web/sites/default/files/civicrm
./web/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm
./web/libraries/civicrm
./vendor/civicrm
user@server /var/www/html/site/drupal $ ls -l web/modules/contrib/civicrm
total 212
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev  1686 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.config.php.drupal
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   275 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.info.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev  5386 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.install
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   102 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.libraries.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   134 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.links.menu.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   346 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.links.task.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev 11690 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.module
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev    73 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.permissions.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   866 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.routing.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   471 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.services.yml
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev  2492 Aug 21 09:50 civicrm.user.inc
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   765 Aug 21 09:50 composer.json
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev   649 Aug 21 09:50 COPYRIGHT.txt
drwxrwxr-x+  2 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 css
drwxrwxr-x+  2 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 drush
drwxrwxr-x+  6 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 icons
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev 35147 Aug 21 09:50 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x+  3 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 modules
-rw-rwxr--+  1 user dev  2989 Aug 21 09:50 README.md
drwxrwxr-x+ 10 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 src
drwxrwxr-x+  2 user dev  4096 Aug 21 09:50 templates
user@server /var/www/html/site/drupal $ ls -l vendor/civicrm/
total 48
drwxrwxr-x+  5 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:51 civicrm-asset-plugin
drwxrwxr-x+ 25 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:51 civicrm-core
drwxrwxr-x+  6 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:51 civicrm-cxn-rpc
drwxrwxr-x+ 30 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:52 civicrm-packages
drwxrwxr-x+  4 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:51 composer-downloads-plugin
drwxrwxr-x+  5 user dev 4096 Oct 19 11:52 cv
```

Hope that helps.

if you need any more let me know.

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same problem after updating from CiviCRM 5.29.1 to 5.30.0 and then 5.30.1.  My file layout looks like the one above though web/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm was empty.  I assume crm-menubar.css  should be here: <drupal_site>/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/css/crm-menubar.css.  What else am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, I believe there's a bug.

Comment: I tried a fresh install following the instructions, but still see the same issue.  I see it has been reported as a bug and claims to have been solved (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2137) but I am still unclear how.  Enabling patching in composer gives a string of 'Could not apply patch!' errors, presumably because the modules in question have already been patched.

Comment: I've done some more investigation - A Drupal7 installation was fine.  I did a fresh install of Drupal 9 and CiviCRM.  No problem except for an error message about text/html mime type in the browser console.  I then changed the locale from en-US to en-GB, and lo and behold, the issue surfaced.  I had unpacked the localisation files before doing that.

Comment: To replicate the above issue, all that was needed was to save the localisation information with no change, i.e. the locale change was a red herring.  I'm not expert enough in the inner workings of CiviCRM to determine exactly what is happening, this call is where the error is thrown:
   \CRM_Utils_Hook::buildAsset($name, $params, $mimeType, $content);
    if ($mimeType === NULL && $content === NULL) {
      throw new UnknownAssetException("Unrecognized asset name: $name");
    }
The $mimeType and $content variables are both null on entering and exiting the buildAsset function.

Comment: The problem changes to a browser console error of:`GET https://jupiter.local:447/civicrm/asset/builder?an=crm-menubar.css&ap=q1bKTc0rTUoscs7PyS9SslJSNkwCQSUdpYzUzPSMEiUrEwMdpaSi1MTsgvzMPCDf3MyiFgA%3D&ad=969a455ba78190ebc134456b8e04dc2a net::ERR_ABORTED 404` and the menu bar disappears when you disable asset caching.  Where is the asset builder trying to find crm-menubar.css?

Comment: See also [Upgrade to 5.30.x causes "Unrecognized asset name: crm-menubar.css" under Drupal 8 or 9](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2218)